# Error Assets/qwe.cs(22,35): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `<internal>' Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

whats the problem in the code? thank you.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class qwe : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject cube;
    public float speed=500;
    GameObject zxc;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetButtonUp("Jump")){
            GameObject CUBE = (GameObject)Instantiate(cube, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            CUBE.rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector3(-speed,0,0));
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision theCollision)
    {
        if(theCollision.gameObject.name == “cube”)
        {
            Destroy(theCollision.gameObject);
            Debug.Log(“We have hit the wall”);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the code really contain those *incorrect* `“cutesy”`-quotes? If so, fix them so they look like `"this"`. Also, which is line number 22?

Comment: That would be line 22 if you count from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

use these " " quotation marks:

```
Debug.Log("We have hit the wall");
```

instead of “ ” quotation marks:

```
Debug.Log(“We have hit the wall”);
```